# In Outlook 2013, is there some way to turn off the annoying calendar detail pop-up on mouse-over?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently started using Outlook 2013 for work and one thing that drives me crazy is the unwanted and unnecessary calendar event details pop-ups on mouse-over.  Please see the image for clarity on what I mean, as I'm not sure what this feature is officially referred to. I scoured the settings for display, calendar, customizations and did online searches for information but have found none.

[image]

Comment: It's not happening on "mouse over", it's on "mouse hover".  So if you don't want further information about what's under the mouse, then don't hover your mouse over it for more than a second. ;)

Comment: Related Info: [ToolTips and Control Tips Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863055(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Things to try :

1. In Outlook *File -> Options -> Calendar*, under Scheduling assistant,
   uncheck the option "Show Calendar details in ScreenTip".
2. Check if in *Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the mouse easier to use*,
   the item "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse" is unchecked.
3. If you use a touchpad there might be more possible actions.
   Is that your case?

Comment: I think it might be a registry setting http://superuser.com/a/1332343

Comment: @StevenPenny: Try this registry update. But if it works this post becomes a duplicate.

Comment: Try it, and let me know if it helps.

Comment: This question wasnt the problem i was having - hence why I asked the other question - i was thinking an answer to this might lead to an answer to mine - but i found my answer first - so now im thinking maybe the answer to mine will lead to an answer to this - but at this point i dont really care the outcome of this question