# Disable hover popup outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

When i hover over an email contact, it produces a popup. How can I stop outlook
from doing this

I tried file, options, general, user interface options, dont show screentips;
but it seems that is not the option that controls it.

> [image: hover]

Comment: Probably an add in, see if anything here helps...https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2013_release/how-can-i-disable-the-on-hover-details-pop-up-in/6d588acd-5e65-46ac-b797-29ac11ee9081

Comment: I can't test this, but these are the instructions for Office 2010: http://leeowens337.blogspot.com/2010/10/outlook-2010-contact-card-hover-over.html . It's a registry setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a REG file that covers Outlook 2013 and 2010:

```clj
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\ContactCard]
"TurnOffHoverFunctionality"=dword:1

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\ContactCard]
"TurnOffHoverFunctionality"=dword:1
```

http://leeowens337.blogspot.com/2010/10/outlook-2010-contact-card-hover-over.html